# wpf listbox with static variable

Tags: wpf, static, listbox

i have a problem with my listbox. If i want to change the variables in the listbox i got an error because the variable is not static. Can somebody explain me how i can make the listBox1 to an Object ?

```
<ListBox i:Name="listBox1"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" MaxWidth="683" PreviewMouseDown="listView_PreviewMouseDown"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,452,0,0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" Height="Auto" >
        <ListBoxItem>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding listboxwertextra}" />
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

My class maininformtation :

```
    public class maininformation
    {
    public string listboxwertextra { get; set; }
    }
```

The Funktion:

```
    public static void reloadlistbox ()
    {

             List<maininformation> items = new List<maininformation>();
              items.Add(new maininformation() { listboxwertextra = "hallo" });
             listBox1.ItemsSource = items;
    }
```

Comment: *i got an error because the variable is not static*... I believe that you are mistaken. What exactly does the error say? *Can somebody explain me how i can make the listBox1 to an Object?*... what for? What do you actually want to achieve here?

Comment: Static method cannot have access to listbox object. You want to do this.listBox1.ItemsSource... but statis does not have "this", get rid of static in this case.

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'listbox1' i want to call the funktion from an other class and he allways tells me that "the public void reloadlistbox ()" should be static

Comment: pass object of Window to that class otherwise you will not have an access to its methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var obj = new MyClass();
    obj.Method(this);

    class MyClass()
    {
        public void Method(Window wind)
        {
            wind.YourNonStaticMethod();
        }
    }
```

But why do not you call object of another class, do whatever you want, retrieve some kind of data if needed and then update your Listbox.

```
public void ReloadListbox()
    {
        var yourClass = new YourClass();
        listBox1.ItemsSource = yourClass.SendMeData();
    }
```